# Compiling a .cpp file with a .o (object file)

Tags: sqlite, linker, g++, object-files

I was trying to use some sqlite3 and then I couldn't compile it with g++. I have learned from another question that said I have to make the sqlite3.c file into sqlite3.o file. I did that with gcc. Now I have my source code as test.cpp and sqlite3.o. How to compile them together with g++?

Answer (score 0):

By compiling them together with g++:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp sqlite3.o
```